# Python, summarize daily data in dataframe to monthly and quarterly

Tags: python, pandas

I have already loaded my data into Pandas dataframe.

Example:

```
Date        Price
2012/12/02  141.25
2012/12/05  132.64
2012/12/06  132.11
2012/12/21  141.64                                                     
2012/12/25  143.19  
2012/12/31  139.66  
2013/01/05  145.11  
2013/01/06  145.99  
2013/01/07  145.97
2013/01/11  145.11  
2013/01/12  145.99  
2013/01/24  145.97
2013/02/23  145.11  
2013/03/24  145.99  
2013/03/28  145.97
2013/04/28  145.97
2013/05/24  145.97
2013/06/23  145.11  
2013/07/24  145.99  
2013/08/28  145.97
2013/09/28  145.97
```

Just two columns, one is data and one is price.

Now how to group or resample the data starts from 2013 to monthly and quarterly df?

Monthly:

```
Date        Price
2013/01/01  Monthly total
2013/02/01  Monthly total
2013/03/01  Monthly total
2013/04/01  Monthly total
2013/05/01  Monthly total
2013/06/01  Monthly total
2013/07/01  Monthly total
2013/08/01  Monthly total  
2013/09/01  Monthly total
```

Quarterly:

```
Date        Price
2013/01/01  Quarterly total
2013/04/01  Quarterly total
2013/07/01  Quarterly total
```

Please note that the monthly and quarterly data need to start from first day of month but in the original dataframe the first day of month data is missing, quantity of valid daily data in each month could vary. Also the original dataframe has data from 2012 to 2013, I only need monthly and quarterly data from beginning of 2013.

I tried something like

```
result1 = df.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month], axis=1).sum()
```

but does not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First convert your Date column into a datetime index:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Then use `resample`. The list of offset aliases is in the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases). For begin of month resample, use `MS`, and `QS` for the quarters:

```
df.resample('QS').sum()
Out[46]: 
              Price
Date               
2012-10-01   830.49
2013-01-01  1311.21
2013-04-01   437.05
2013-07-01   437.93

df.resample('MS').sum()
Out[47]: 
             Price
Date              
2012-12-01  830.49
2013-01-01  874.14
2013-02-01  145.11
2013-03-01  291.96
2013-04-01  145.97
2013-05-01  145.97
2013-06-01  145.11
2013-07-01  145.99
2013-08-01  145.97
2013-09-01  145.97
```

Comment: Fantastic!!  I struggled 2 days on groupby function, lambda expression...Thank you so much!

Comment: So giving this, what if I have duplicate date, df.set_index still works? Or I need to process the duplicate data data first?

Comment: It doesn't matter, give it a try, change a date in your sample to get a dupe and you will see everything will work as expected.