# How to add rows into data frame in order to organize time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
        AUX     TER
11/2014 2.0     10.0
01/2015 23.0    117.0
03/2015 57.0    65.0
04/2015 1.0     1.0
05/2015 16.0    20.0
07/2015 19.0    30.0
```

I want to fill the values for months that are not in data frame with 0
like this

```
        AUX     TER
11/2014 2.0     10.0
12/2014 0       0
01/2015 23.0    117.0
03/2015 57.0    65.0
04/2015 1.0     1.0
05/2015 16.0    20.0
06/2015 0       0
07/2015 19.0    30.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Change your index to `datetime`

   ```
   df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m/%Y')
   ```
2. Use `asfreq` with the `fill_value` argument

   ```
   df.asfreq('MS', fill_value=0)

                AUX    TER
   2014-11-01   2.0   10.0
   2014-12-01   0.0    0.0
   2015-01-01  23.0  117.0
   2015-02-01   0.0    0.0
   2015-03-01  57.0   65.0
   2015-04-01   1.0    1.0
   2015-05-01  16.0   20.0
   2015-06-01   0.0    0.0
   2015-07-01  19.0   30.0
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below to [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
s=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.reindex(pd.date_range(s.min(),s.max()+pd.DateOffset(months=1),freq='M')
           .strftime('%m/%Y'),fill_value=0)
```

---

```
          AUX    TER
11/2014   2.0   10.0
12/2014   0.0    0.0
01/2015  23.0  117.0
02/2015   0.0    0.0
03/2015  57.0   65.0
04/2015   1.0    1.0
05/2015  16.0   20.0
06/2015   0.0    0.0
07/2015  19.0   30.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `df.resample("M").mean().fillna(0)`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\s+", parse_dates=['date'])
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
df = df.resample("M").mean().fillna(0)
df.index = df.index.strftime("%m/%Y")

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          AUX    TER
11/2014   2.0   10.0
12/2014   0.0    0.0
01/2015  23.0  117.0
02/2015   0.0    0.0
03/2015  57.0   65.0
04/2015   1.0    1.0
05/2015  16.0   20.0
06/2015   0.0    0.0
07/2015  19.0   30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have  a datetime format, you can try:

`df.resample('MS').mean()`

following this post: [Python, summarize daily data in dataframe to monthly and quarterly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554396/python-summarize-daily-data-in-dataframe-to-monthly-and-quarterly)