# Resample time series data to find tail characteristics

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily time series data. I am able to convert to monthly (or quarterly) time series and obtain monthly mean using the resample function, provided by this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554396/python-summarize-daily-data-in-dataframe-to-monthly-and-quarterly)

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.resample('MS').mean()
```

Instead of monthly mean, I am interested in obtaining monthly skewness (or kurtosis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this with [`scipy.stats.skew`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html):

```
from scipy.stats import skew 

df.resample('MS').agg(skew)
```

Or with [`scipy.stats.kurtosis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html):

```
from scipy.stats import kurtosis 

df.resample('MS').agg(kurtosis)
```

Or as  @Ben.T suggests, you can use the functions that pandas provides ([`pd.Series.skew`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.skew.html), [`pd.Series.kurtosis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.kurtosis.html)):

```
df.resample('MS').agg([pd.Series.skew, pd.Series.kurtosis])

#Same as:
#df.resample('MS').skew()
#or:
#df.resample('MS').kurtosis()
```

Comment: Sure, great idea, I forgot about them. Just added that option, thanks @Ben.T :)